# Implementing a c++ iterator : satisfying Swappable

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, containers, swap

A c++11 Iterator must be "Swappable".

When implementing a swap function, do I need to support swapping iterators from two different containers? I know that comparing them is unspecified, but I can't find anything about swap.

Comment: Usually you don't need to implement it - `std::swap` is just fine.